# How to parallelize alpha in glmnet function (and not cv.glmnet)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, purrr, glmnet, furrr

I am going to use a penalized regression model from the `glmnet` package on a panel dataset. Being panel means that I will test the model not with cross validation but with rolling origin, so I will not use the `cv.glmnet` function, that works only with cross-validation.  Instead, I will use the default `glmnet` function. This function have two parameters that need to be optimized, `lambda` and `alpha`. `lambda`is allowed to be an array, and if so, a model for each element in the array is fitted, but `alpha` is required to be a scalar. I am interested in running models for different `alpha` values. So far, I am doing this sequentially with a for loop, like in the following example (in this example I use the `BostonHousing` dataset for simplicity, though is not panel data)

```
# Load libraries
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
library(tidyverse)

# Load dataset
data(BostonHousing)

# Split into train / test
x_train = BostonHousing %>% slice(1:400) %>%  select(-c(medv, chas)) %>% as.matrix()
x_test = BostonHousing %>% slice(401:n()) %>% select(-c(medv, chas)) %>% as.matrix()

y_train = BostonHousing %>%  slice(1:400) %>%  select(medv) %>% as.matrix()
y_test = BostonHousing %>%  slice(401:n()) %>%  select(medv) %>% as.matrix()

# Define grid for parameters
lambda_param = 10^seq(-3, 1, by=0.5)
alpha_param = seq(0, 1, 0.1)

# Sequential approach
mse_sequential = matrix(NA,length(lambda_param), length(alpha_param))
for(i in seq_along(alpha_param))
{
  fit_seq = glmnet(x=x_train, y=y_train, family='gaussian', lambda=lambda_param, alpha=alpha_param[i])
  p = predict(fit_seq, newx=x_test)
  mse_sequential[,i] = map_dbl(seq_along(lambda_param), function(j){mean((p[,j]-y_test)^2)})
}
```

This approach works, but seems like highly inefficient to me, and I considered parallelizing it. I tried to use the `furrr` package (that allows for paralelization of the `purrr` functions) but I am facing two problems:

### Problem 1

The folllowing piece of code (suposedly) runs `furrr` sequentially:

```
library(furrr)
plan(sequential)
glmnet_alpha = partial(glmnet, x = x_train, y = y_train, family = "gaussian", weights = rep(1, nrow(x_train)), lambda=lambda_param)
fit = future_map(alpha_param, glmnet_alpha)
```

But the solution achieved using a for loop differs from the solution achieved using `furrr`. For example, having a look to the coefficients for `lambda=10` and `alpha=0`:

```
fit_seq = glmnet(x=x_train, y=y_train, family='gaussian', lambda=10, alpha=0)
as.vector(fit_seq$beta)
as.vector(fit[[1]]$beta[,1])
```

## Problem 2

If I try to run `furrr` in parallel I get an error message:

```
plan(multiprocess)
glmnet_alpha = partial(glmnet, x = x_train, y = y_train, family = "gaussian", weights = rep(1, nrow(x_train)), lambda=lambda_param)
fit = future_map(alpha_param, glmnet_alpha)

Error in drop(y) : objeto 'y_train' no encontrado
```

So any help understanding what is going on here, or providing an alternative approach for running this in parallel would be appreciated.

Comment: your for loop runs very quickly on my system.. When you parallelize, you also need to take into account the time to send the environment or objects to the other CPUs, and to combine it again, so I really don't think you gain much

Comment: also if you check your fit with future_map, the coefficients are all the same. meaning your partial did not work... I think you need to sort out how to use partial correctly

Comment: I think you would be best of using a meta package for this sort of thing: caret, mlr or mlr3 are my recommendations. I recommend picking one of them and reading up a bit and if you get stuck post another question. Caret is probably the most popular and well known. I am a fan of mlr3.